# Rearrange Components when button is clicked (Button also adds JXCollapsiblePane)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, swingx

so I'm having a problem with my buttons in java. I created my buttons through extending a JButton so I can have all of my buttons looking the same. Now, I added an ActionListener to the constructor of that button, and the ActionListener decides what action to run based on the text of the button. (Using

```
String buttonString = e.getActionCommand();
```

and then uses a switch/case to check the text.)

At the moment, I have it where when I click a button, it adds a new JXCollapsiblePane, but it's added to the bottom of the panel. How do I get it to be added to underneath the buttons?

An SSCCE based on my code, which is roughly the same:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXCollapsiblePane;

public class ActualCode{
    public static JPanel newPanel;
    public static JFrame frame;

    public static void createGUI(){
        JButton newButton= new JButton("TextButton");
        newButton.addActionListener(new ButtonClickActionK());

        JPanel newPanel = new JPanel();
        newPanel.setVisible(true);
        newPanel.setOpaque(false);
        newPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        newPanel.add(newButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Command Line Test");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(newPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setSize(new Dimension(720, 480));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createGUI();

            } // public void run() Closing
        }); // SwingUtilities Closing
    }

}

 class ButtonClickActionK extends ActualCode implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String str = e.getActionCommand();

        switch (str) {


        case "TextButton":
            //TODO Make a JXCollapsiblePane slide out
            System.out.println("Slide out panel not made yet!");
            JXCollapsiblePane testp = new JXCollapsiblePane();
            newPanel.add(testp);
            break;

        default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Erm, this is embarrasing! Something went (horribly) wrong...");
        }
    }
}
```

Stack Trace Error:

```
Slide out panel not made yet!
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.warlords.warlordsorganizer.ButtonClickActionK.actionPerformed(ActualCode.java:64)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The MAIN problem I'm having is just how to add the JXCollapsiblePane directly under the button, and how to set the toggle to said button. The rest I can probably figure out by myself.

Anything else I can provide to help?

Comment: the NPE is due to the not initialized class field newPanel. That said: the setup is rather weird a) why do you subclass ActualCode? All you need is a Action/Listener b) subclassing JSomething usually is a bad idea, they are meant to be used as-are and configured as needed

Answer (score 2):

Here's a snippet which

- is adding the collapsible without needing a reference to the panel: simply add to parent of the source of ActionEvent
- not extending anything unrelated (to its ActionListener-ness)

Note that the parent container of a JXCollapsiblePane must use a LayoutManager which respects the collapsible's preferredSize always, otherwise you'll get unpredicatable effects on collapse/expand

```
class ButtonClickActionK implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String str = e.getActionCommand();
        Component source = (Component) e.getSource();

        switch (str) {


        case "TextButton":
            Container parent = source.getParent();
            JXCollapsiblePane testp = new JXCollapsiblePane();
            testp.add(new JLabel("dummy, just to see we are open"));
            parent.add(testp);
            parent.revalidate();
            break;

        default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(source, 
               "Erm, this is embarrasing! Something went (horribly) wrong...");
        }
    }
}

// usage
JButton newButton= new JButton("TextButton");
newButton.addActionListener(new ButtonClickActionK());
// note: _not_ using a class field
JComponent newPanel = new JPanel(new VerticalLayout());
newPanel.add(newButton);
```